# Make JS detect position on page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a one-page website, before that it had 3 different pages, and the navigation bar's link to the current page turned to ´id="selected´

```
#selected {
background-color:white;
color: #645406;
cursor: default;
}
```

when you are on that page. 
Now it's a bit harder, as the links work just as anchor links.
I'd need a script that would detect where the user is scrolling, and automatically turn the anchor's link to ´id="selected"´ when the user scrolls over the anchor.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mbSXB/

Comment: And your question is?..

Comment: So you would like to have a function that fires as a user scrolls down a page, changing a given element's `id` to `selected`. What is your specific question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/8NKqf/1/

```
$(function() {
    var anchors = $('.anchor');
    var navLinks = $('.navigointi a');

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop    = $(window).scrollTop();
        var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var activeSectionAnchor, hash;

        anchors.each(function() {
            if ($(this).offset().top < scrollTop + clientHeight) {
                activeSectionAnchor = $(this);
            }
        });

        hash = "#" + activeSectionAnchor.attr('name');

        activeLink = navLinks.removeClass('selected').filter('[href="' + hash + '"]');

        activeLink.addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey @akrasman ! Nice job, it works perfectly! Could you also add a smooth scrolling? I'm a noob in JS, so I couldn't success in adding it.

Comment: Smooth scrolling by doing what? When you click on navigation links?

Comment: Yes. http://cferdinandi.github.io/smooth-scroll/ it's so simple but it won't work for me... The script is in the same folder and I did it exactly like that. Also, I've been trying to add NiceScroll 3, but it ends with the same result.